# Can I force my iPhone 5S to ONLY use towers from a specific US state?

Tags: ios

I live in Laughlin, Nevada (right on the border of Nevada and Arizona). Some casino apps require you to be in Nevada to access them, but the problem is that sometimes my phone picks up on Arizona cell phone towers (even when I'm on the Nevada side of the border). Is it possible to force my iPhone to ONLY use Nevada towers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the towers are using the same working bands, as far as I know what you are asking is not possible. The phone complete the association with the tower that provide the higher signal, you can't control that.

Comment: Have you determined if geo-location or a VPN to your house or place of work in nevada would pin your location to the state?